# Get the path of the current image - jQuery

Tags: javascript, image, runtime, jquery

I am using [this photo gallery from Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/14/sliding-panel-photo-wall-gallery-with-jquery/) to display the images. I've added a button to delete the current image which is clicked [and enlarged]. However this doesn't delete the image which is clicked, but it deletes the first photo in the album.

How do I get the image path of the image which is clicked [i.e. current image]?

This is the jQuery code that I've added to the gallery script:

```
var image = $('#photos').attr("alt");

                /* If delete is called */
                $('#adelete').click(function(){
                //create post data
                    var postData = { 
                        "image" : image
                };

                    //make the call
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "delete.php",
                        data: postData, 
                        success: function(data){
                        alert("Image deleted successfully! " +image+data);  
                        }
                    });
                });
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    $image = $_REQUEST['image'];
    if (isset($image)) {
        unlink($image);
        echo "Success";
    }
?>
```

'photos' is the ID of the image.

```
echo "<img id='photos' src='/thumbs/$image' alt='$dirname/$image' />";
```

If I use `var image = $('#wrapper img').attr("alt");` as in the gallery code, it gives an `undefined` error and no images are deleted. I'm assuming this is because the enlarged image is loaded at runtime.

Comment: try `var image = $('#photos').prop("alt");` inside your `.click(...)` ( jQuery v1.6)

Comment: did that. it deletes the first photo in the album not the image whose thumbnail was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the image that you are putting on the page isn't the same image element that is loaded in the panel.  You should search for the matching image in your content area that has the same url as the image in the panel that you want to delete, then get it's `alt` attribute. [Do you really need `alt` or couldn't you figure out from the `src` what the directory is on the server?  If so, that would save you from having to do the second look up; you could just pass back the url from the panel image.]

```
/* If delete is called */
$('#adelete').click(function(){
    var src = $('#wrapper img').attr('src');

    var image = $('#content img:has([src="' + src + '"])').attr('alt');

    //create post data
        var postData = { 
            "image" : image
    };

    //make the call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: postData, 
        success: function(data){
        alert("Image deleted successfully! " +image+data);  
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the pointer! I did not realize that the src attribute of the image element changed with the loading of the full image in the panel. I changed the alt to src of `#wrapper img` element and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `var image = $('#photos').attr("alt");` inside your `.click(...)`

Comment: `.click` event of photo or the delete button? The way this gallery works is, on the click of the thumbnail image, it loads the full image. On the click of the full image, it goes back to album displaying thumbnail images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about all that other mess, but to get the path of an image that was clicked just do this:

```
$('#photos').click(function() {
  var path = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

Comment: also can use `$(this).prop("src")` from jQuery v1.6

Comment: I tried the code, it didn't work. The way this gallery works is, on the click of the thumbnail image, it loads the full image. On the click of the full image, it goes back to album displaying thumbnail images.